# Number of Nonnegative integers = number of integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just came across the idea that says the number of non-negative integers is equal to the number of integers. How is this possible? Isn't it true that non-negative integers are a subset of all integers? Then, it should follow that the number of all integers is bigger, twice at least, than the number of non-negative integers?

If the passage is indeed true, what is the implication of this?

Comment: Well they're both infinite, so they're not really "numbers" in the sense that we can intelligently say things like "twice as big", don't you think?

Comment: Though $2\times\aleph_0$ is a perfectly sensible cardinal number. It just happens to equal $\aleph_0$. I think this is more to the point when learning to reason about cardinal addition: infinite cardinals just work differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that if we can put a set into a one-to-one correspondence with the Natural Numbers, then the sets have the same cardinality $\aleph_0$.

So the number of nonnegative integers (we can also call this the cardinality of the set $\mathbb{N}$) is the same as the number of integers (we can call this the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}$). We can show that $\mathbb{Z}$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$ because the function $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by:

$$f(z) = \begin{cases} 2z + 2 \quad\quad \;if\;z\geq0\\-2z-1, \quad if\; z<0\end{cases}$$

is a bijection.[*]

This can be a little tricky to wrap your head around - if you think that it's not possible because both sets "go to infinity" and one of them seems "smaller" than the other, remember that infinity is not a number.

---

[*] The function described there maps from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as the positive integers. Given that the OP asked for the nonnegative integers, i.e. $\mathbb{N}$ indexed from $0$, the function is not perfectly applicable, but the idea remains the same, and modifying the function to map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to the nonnegative integers is easy, perhaps best left as an exercise for OP.

Comment: I kind of get it now. Are you saying that quantifiable terms cannot apply to infinity?

Comment: This is not related to Cantor's diagonal proof. That proof is about there being strictly larger infinite sets, this is simply about the definition of equipotent.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You are right. I was just reminded of it by the question. I've removed my reference to it from the answer.

Comment: @gelolopez Well, yes. Try not to think about infinity too much, instead just focus on the definitions and the logical argument. Worrying about infinity can make this much more difficult to understand.

Comment: Thanks @Newb. Was just shocked with the idea. Anyway, I found an interesting proof of the idea using sequences. I guess, that should satisfy my curiosity.